# Ejabberd slows down when large stanzas are sent

Tags: debugging, websocket, erlang, elixir, ejabberd

Ejabberd version: 19.9.0

Upon sending OMEMO message (using websockets), e.g.

```
<message
    xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en' to='fedora@im-docker.rationaletech.com/2862250025' from='nikola@im-docker.rationaletech.com/3406627301' type='chat' id='ec8885cd-d63e-4a7a-b25f-beaa42a603c8'>
    <archived by='fedora@im-docker.rationaletech.com' id='1574939718713739'
        xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'/>
        <stanza-id by='fedora@im-docker.rationaletech.com' id='1574939718713739'
            xmlns='urn:xmpp:sid:0'/>
            <encrypted
                xmlns='eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl'>
                <header sender='nikola@im-docker.rationaletech.com' sid='3406627301'>
                    <key prekey='true' receiver='fedora@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='2422992889'>Myjlg7TYDAgxMAMSIQW1dAuisDMW9x9NMvbld9cYrrkO2sCnMu5KlInYb7zOTRohBZ+vLgmuHnqw1Pp4UPHMORgPMT+hYoKwSxEWodHPCycBInIzCiEFawmeEU2FYrU53idtBEhkjCrGt5PK4aWmOnUcKwBxemUQRhgAIkC4p51BI53WjN2wNlgyM8azInFCuk5vakJsJksyEq7ia0LcE9TlZ+ygL/0JYmvyiopLhaVc0LnpW/ixtdXwa16oEHNyOajO1r0=</key>
                    <key prekey='true' receiver='fedora@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='2509209946'>Myjlg7TYDAhJMAESIQUJ51hn28dskUoJ+NCG5Vm1ZXP1YOyQSQEf4sab+kDJYhohBZ+vLgmuHnqw1Pp4UPHMORgPMT+hYoKwSxEWodHPCycBInIzCiEF/5BXLSpk+XJSC/2M2hOP+DGhmvreLhXfG1apUYCLb2IQRhgAIkBBTaB4DEEQJqKDiWJOQzNQhpw7r7osMW4d6MzlBUOhil7xxgXgvXCI6zeWYgUD/3/lIZVSsSl9I719XpG9y27qfOJRQtLdP1k=</key>
                    <key prekey='true' receiver='fedora@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='3618986588'>Myjlg7TYDAg3MAQSIQVIPzGNN0nypISB7FPrljHFu2U1v/xutcn75JTF6CmHdhohBZ+vLgmuHnqw1Pp4UPHMORgPMT+hYoKwSxEWodHPCycBInIzCiEFdf7SVhrxDiAtIYvgDzGxELyv5SBvbTKXJ2w0koLlbycQRhgAIkDfUOb09tsKnC3MHiMgaKS8jDzp0Hf7bB58VZke4zhP5JYYCVEMBcNFZGPZmsdyfFERgZ+qOWuL7w4tvECY6OIoOL7oYcDZaws=</key>
                    <key prekey='false' receiver='fedora@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='2862250025'>MwohBdoQz6FKWe8sCrYSUWy/pFw2iZhUnvCF+oSrhOimqmM+EAEYACJA7tigMY/7W93aIKdfAjPDhXE92ECVCXaQU3jDNJZTp1ZTwkA4AnWcOT/I9vBPM7+2orMz8O4sNN5jxEv8V/uRZEs7BzxUjLPM</key>
                    <key prekey='false' receiver='nikola@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='2383543931'>MwohBdP2fJcvz2TW4D82Ga/wfYfYsem3IfBjY+bGkPlZGuQTEEMYAiJAdI6kUOj8mcmVCFuzorzg5p/wZIX5xrxZn3cO2+dLlVBygx4czFQ0YjwIIyiYSnqJCiwxoZ63q7mrMXMQlCu+hHvcXHvmKOJZ</key>
                    <key prekey='true' receiver='nikola@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='2840952004'>Myjlg7TYDAglMAISIQWwNkc4CUtJXuxbK70xFp6C9G8Ty1G98V2WbZqUooYwGhohBZ+vLgmuHnqw1Pp4UPHMORgPMT+hYoKwSxEWodHPCycBInIzCiEFl80r5eU1gFX9Lrvin016vYEdyqV7cYPUmmPrVJaBaBoQRhgAIkCWgUvIrWlTIWDp6ckZiB96fkbyxo0uVhO31OSJE19cXGA6/hMLyrRs7nzOu18brViag6XNDQVHHM1OEPnihQD0Rnflufhbo3Q=</key>
                    <key prekey='true' receiver='nikola@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='2998742495'>Myjlg7TYDAhAMAESIQXJta5zfQPW2VXcVOCMnIc3a/LZSuoa8tW6VWAkGlxxPhohBZ+vLgmuHnqw1Pp4UPHMORgPMT+hYoKwSxEWodHPCycBInIzCiEFhn7zIoGXOk8wXGw5KN8mSsmiyKT7onzFdRSLuVxEK1MQRhgAIkATGXdHjeIOlekk5NXeiELGxXf1GCFSYsE8Zqe9H9ruqtt1nGYfd7IPBudPrqTECapLS7Kqz945oUHpM66czTd7NjKhyXhb3F0=</key>
                    <key prekey='true' receiver='nikola@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='2785411843'>Myjlg7TYDAg5MAISIQXDysL22t0RVmIIZOfUdUOEgjU7B3V4GA0a7osgBg9aYBohBZ+vLgmuHnqw1Pp4UPHMORgPMT+hYoKwSxEWodHPCycBInIzCiEFKYdGNmwdYAYJpnw5fPZfvFCNtNl1/ZCDt6E3Dz+9rG0QRhgAIkBxfV1mldGWy8JBCGQXW3ITm6HRRWA/EaWgWlbDvWYTl3K+DQW+Zzj033nXARSdDos0ScIenWB/JmWxmTcKEp/7lCzmEiwMqMU=</key>
                    <key prekey='true' receiver='nikola@im-docker.rationaletech.com' rid='2985212938'>Myjlg7TYDAgmMAUSIQW82JxHAPf9UfWeqigNppDqcO2r0eTBc4WFZ1wCLmcvXBohBZ+vLgmuHnqw1Pp4UPHMORgPMT+hYoKwSxEWodHPCycBInIzCiEFDjt46Fv4vMhjz6bQb/edXCQRFcr7DsNy1fqpR30OOV0QRhgAIkBKfl/0Y+QeKoJ3M7+3OdCFEvR9NLFKCmLHu2U3MWdScbt4dEvALffwT9JiiYmT1OB7jgtjEw9LeuGPehmjFIvBgozS7Hqv7bs=</key>
                    <iv>hxJQrzzNX3LHbXS5</iv>
                </header>
                <payload>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</payload>
            </encrypted>
            <store
                xmlns='urn:xmpp:hints'/>
                <active
                    xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
                </message>
```

it takes almost 10 seconds for this message to be processed and passed to other client (server and both clients are on same local machine). Usual (simple) stanza routing time  negligible (<1 second).

How can I troubleshot this problem? What are possible fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas for you to try:

If you send that same stanza, but using c2s connected clients instead of websockets, does it still take 10 seconds to arrive?

If you send that stanza without the large payload element, using websocket clients, does it still take 10 seconds?

And if the sender client uses websocket bu the destination does not? And viceversa?

Comment: I fugured it out by enabling log level 5 and tracking down logs with significant delays in between. ejabberd_websocket uses shaper which leads to delay (https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd_websocket.erl#L457). So solution was to increase normal shaper config to 10000 (https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/ejabberd.yml.example#L123). Is there recommended config that goes with OMEMO as OMEMO could be large?